# URL Rewrite with PHP on Windows IIS

Tags: php, iis-6, url-rewriting

Unfortunately I don't have access to the Windows Server in question, so I would need instructions as to how I could do this so I can pass it on.

Basically, I am using PHP on a Windows IIS 6 and I need to be able to rewrite the URLs as you would with a .htaccess file.

I need to turn 
`example.com/index.php?page=about`

into

`example.com/about/`

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have access to the IIS server itself, then you are out of luck.

If you can convince the server operators to install an URL rewriting engine, like [Ionic's Isapi Rewrite Filter](http://iirf.codeplex.com/) or [Helicon's ISAPI/Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) for example, then you can use regular `.htaccess` files just like you would with Apache and mod_rewrite.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! With using the Ionic one, what instructions do I provide the host in order to set up the redirect as above? Thanks again

Comment: @Tim: The install instructions for the filters are on the respective home pages. Be aware that the ISAPI/Rewrite *Lite* does not support de-centralized .htaccess files, but the paid version does. You want the paid version. Ionic's filter is free and looks promising but I don't have practical experience with it. Instructions for the specific redirect apply more to yourself than the server operators. See @Pradeep Singh's answer below to get an idea how the RewriteRule could look like, and also consult the documentation, as these engines are not necessarily 100% mod_rewrite compatible.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [this](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) plugin to IIS, as using regex.

> ```
> IIS URL Rewrite 2.0 enables Web administrators to create
> powerful rules to implement URLs that are easier for users to
> remember and easier for search engines to find. By using rule
> ```
>
> templates, 
>       rewrite maps, .NET providers, and other functionality integrated into
>   IIS Manager, Web 
>       administrators can easily set up rules
>        to define URL rewriting behavior based on HTTP headers,
>        HTTP response or request headers, IIS server variables, and even complex
>
> ```
> programmatic rules. In addition, Web administrators can perform
> ```
>
> redirects, 
>       send custom responses, or stop HTTP requests

[Here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/) it explains how to use it.

Comment: I know it's an old answer, but still URL Rewrite is for IIS 7 and he requested for IIS 6.